Firebase: Why is my email verification not being sent?
I am trying to sendEmailVerification using Firebase but it's failing.
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/auth/register", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email,
        password,
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
            return res.json()
    }).then((data) => {
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    }).then(() => {
        console.log("data", auth.currentUser)
        sendEmailVerification(auth.currentUser)
        .then(() => {
            navigate('/')
        })

    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });
};

It seems like there'a delay to sendEmailVerification. If I sign up user1, no email verification is sent, but after I sign up user2, user1 email is then sent. Why is there a delay? I want the user email verification to be immediately sent after registration.

If the Firebase hosted service isn't working the way you expect, contact Firebase support directly.  If the API calls return successfully but don't do their work, we can't say what the problem is - it's all on the Firebase backend outside of our view as volunteers (the client library does not actually send the emails).

@DougStevenson the sure signin doesn't immediately change auth current user.

signInWithEmailAndPassword returns a promise to indicate completion or error, but you're not doing anything with it.

This was a problem with my promise code. I needed to return this line:
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);

